# The browser does not get closed when test case is completed in visual studio

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, visual-studio-2019

When the test case is completed the browser remains open and does not get closed. How can i resolve the issue?

Comment: Please show the constructor for the `Name` class and show where you initialize your `WDriver` object

Comment: please see the edits

Answer (score 1):

So in your `wd` method with the `[TestInitialize]` attribute, you're creating your `WebDriver` instance. You're also closing it in the `Cleanup` method with the `[TestCleanup]` method. However, in your test method named `search`, you're creating a `Name` object which creates its own `WebDriver` instance, namely by calling `b.wd1();`. For more context, I'm referring to this line:

```
[Priority(1)]
[TestMethod]
public void search()
{
    Name b = new Name();
    b.wd1(); // This line is creating an additional `WebDriver` instance
    b.Namesearch();
}
```

The reason that the browser isn't closing is because the `WebDriver` instance being created by `b.wd1();` isn't being closed. In actuality, you're opening 2 browsers and only closing 1 of them.

Comment: I added `b.wd1()` because without this NULL reference exception was occurring

Comment: Because, webdriver value was getting NULL.